# NSMutableString conversion errors

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I have the following code and I'm banging my head against a wall trying to figure out what's producing the errors.

```
NSMutableString *entry = (@"%@ (%@): %@",translatedHeadword,adlerNumber,meaning);
entry = [entry replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"<br/>" withString:@" " options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, entry.length)];
```

The second line is giving two errors: `Implicit conversion of 'NSUInteger' to`NSMutableString`is disallowed with ARC` and `Incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to NSMutableString from NSUInteger.`  But `translatedHeadword`, `adlerNumber`, and `meaning` are all `NSString`s.  `adlerNumber` contains characters representing numbers, but it's still a string.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax `(@"%@", foo)` does not produce string formatting. You need to use `[NSMutableString stringWithFormat:]` to do string formatting.

Also, `replaceOccurrencesOfString:...` returns the number of changed things and *mutates* the string itself. So, it's complaining about the assignment `entry = ...` because the right-hand side is the NSUInteger returned by `replaceOccurencesOfString:...`.